# Passing Javascript Array to php function and call another php function using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this button here to call Javascript function

```
<button class=" btn-primary border border-primary rounded p-2 ms-auto " id="proceed" onclick="proceed_tags()">Proceed </button>
```

The function is to pass selected_keywords_arr  Array to `controller/keywords_suggestion.php`

```
function proceed_tags(){


        if (selected_keywords_arr === undefined || selected_keywords_arr.length == 0) {
            // array empty or does not exist
            alert("you have to select keywords first");
            return;
        }
        var Tags_Data = JSON.stringify(selected_keywords_arr);
        alert("button clicked");

          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'controller/keywords_suggestion.php',
           data:{action,Tags_Data },
           success:function(Success) {
             alert(Success);
           }

      });
       
    }
```

here in `controller/keywords_suggestion.php` I'm trying to capture the array and to check if the button clicked to execute another function
**but it prints this error**
`[Wed Mar 16 18:16:59.919632 2022] [php:warn] [pid 7488:tid 1852] [client ::1:65035] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "action" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\seosystem\\controller\\keywords_suggestion.php on line 25`

```
$keyword_tags_arr = json_decode($_POST['action'],true);

 
 
     if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    var_dump($keyword_tags_arr);
    echo "  <script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"Helllllo\");  ";
    $Keywords_analysis_objj = new Keywords_analysis();
    $Keywords_analysis_objj->Keywords_title_desc();

}
```

Comment: Typo - I think you meant `data:{ "action": Tags_Data }`

Comment: But...don't send JSON data wrapped in form-url-encoded paramters....yuk. Either send pure JSON, or send form-url-encoded data, don't mix and match.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks I did edit it, but I still get an error about failed opening required file how ever I'm sure of the path `<br /><b>Warning</b>:require_once(controller/controller.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or director<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\controller\keywords_suggestion.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> 
`Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'controller/controller.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\controller\keywords_suggestion.php:3`

Comment: I ain't know why it gave an error about requiring some files in `keywords_suggestion.php`
the file starts with `<?php
require_once 'controller/youtubedata.php';
require_once 'controller/controller.php';` 
So it says failed to open them

Comment: Maybe they don't exist, or the path is wrong. I can't see that bit of code, or your filesystem

Comment: @ADyson Actually I call some functions from this file because it has classes and for sure it works but when I pass the array to this file again it prints this I even wrote the full path and still get the same error

Comment: I want to show the tree but on windows a little bit silly, `C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem` and `C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\controller\keywords_suggestion.php`
index.php which has the javascript function 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\index.php`

Comment: it works however I still get the same error but I just replaced the requiring of the file after ` if(isset($_POST["action"]))` so it execute and pass the array then print the error 
`Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class &quot;Exttractdata&quot; not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\controller\keywords_suggestion.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\controller\keywords_suggestion.php(20): Keywords_analysis-&gt;Keywords_title_desc()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\controller\keywords_suggestion.php</b> on line <b>181</b><br />`